# Python OPC-UA client stops reading after a while

Tags: python, opc-ua

I’m writing a code that reads data from an OPC server. This is a summary:

> url = opc.tcpXXXXX
>
> client = Client(url)
>
> client.connect()

And then in a while loop I want to read data from the server for several days:

> While True:
>
> Data1 =client.get_node(“ns=4;i=3”)
>
> Data1_Val = Data1.get_value()
>
> #write it to sql table
>
> time.sleep(120)

I’m reading 20 nodes the same way in the same while loop.
At first, all works fine. But, after a while the script would still be running but without any data acquisition! What I mean is that after about 2 hours, I will no longer get data from the server.

What could possibly be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That will be really difficult to say with so less information…

Anyway if you want to often read the value of a bunch of nodes from the server, you should use the OPC UA subscription.

This will be more efficient and you shouldn’t miss any value

Answer (score 1):

What is your opc server ?

**1-)** Ex. in kepserverex opc server runtime has 2 hour for a free version. then it ill stoped read data and publish to opc server. Maybe other opc servers are like this.

**2-)** OPC servers include some config settings like connection time or alive time or someting like that. Check your server settings.

**3-)** Some Opc servers need certificate, if u connect wihout certificate it ill close session after a while for security.

**4-)** Sometimes our request failed from server , because server cant read data of your wish. This error can lead to logging out, it can also be in the configuration settings of this server.

U should check them, if u can say your opc server name i can search